# lambda/python docker listening address

Tags: docker-compose, aws-lambda

Problem is that lambda/python:3.8 by default using localhost:9001 as listening address and port. Is it possible wit change it to 0.0.0.0 ? it needed to allow external requests to ppt lambda docker.

Comment: This has nothing to do with python-pptx. Can I politely request you to remove the tag? Thanks.